# Is it possible to create SolidWorks files from Autodesk 3Ds Max?

Tags: 3ds-max, solidworks

Is it possible to create SolidWorks files (i.e. *.stl, *.sldasm, *.sldprt, *.stp) from Autodesk 3Ds Max?

Comment: It looks like there may be some third party options you could use. http://www.sharewareconnection.com/3ds-export-for-solidworks.htm

Answer (score 0):

I use 3ds max with *architectural* CAD programs, like ArchiCAD and Revit (so I am not absolutely sure), and I doubt it is possible.  Autodesk aims to lock users into using their products, but you should be able to export a basic interchange format like `.dxf` which you can use a template in SolidWorks.

You may also be able to find third-party conversion tools that can do it.  They are usually pretty expensive, but the time-limited trial versions may be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

3ds Max can export the following formats:

(for unsupported formats, I recommend getting [okino polytrans](http://www.okino.com/conv/conv.htm))

EXPORT:

- 3D Studio (*.3DS)
- Adobe Illustrator (*.AI)
- ASCII Scene Export (*.ASE)
- Lightscape - Material (*.ATR), Blocks (*.BLK), Parameter (*.DF), Layers (*.LAY), Preparation (*.LP), View (*.VW)
- Autodesk DWF (*.DWF)
- Autocad DWG (*.DWG)
- Autocad DXF (*.DXF)
- Autodesk FBX (*.FBX, *.DAE)
- Motion Analysis HTR File (*.HTR)
- IGES (*.IGS)
- JSR-184 (*.M3G)
- Wavefront Object (*.OBJ) and Material (*.MTL)
- StereoLitho (*.STL)
- Shockwave 3D (*.W3D)
- VRML97 (*.WRL)